# cost / mapping function for determining center of object based on detected features

Tags: java, python, algorithm, matlab, tracking

I wrote an object tracker that will try to detect and follow a moving object in a recorded video. In order to maximize the detection rate, my algorithm is using a bunch of detection & tracking algorithms (cascade, foreground & particle tracker). Each tracking algorithm will return me some `point of interest` that might be part of the object that I'm trying to track. Let's assume (for the simplicity of this example) that my object is a rectangle and that the three tracking algorithms returned the points `1`, `2` and `3`:

[image: Step0]

Based on the relation / distance of these three points it is possible to calculate the center of gravity (blue `X` in above image) of the tracked object. So for each frame I might be able to come up with some good estimate of the center of gravity. However, the object might move from one frame to the next:

[image: Step1]

In this example I merely rotated the original object. My algorithm will give me three new points of interest: `1'`,`2'` and `3'`. I could again calculate the center of gravity based on these three new points, but I would throw away important information that I've acquired from the previous frame: based on points `1`, `2` and `3` I already do know something about the relationship of these points and thus by combining the information from `1`, `2` and `3` and `1'`,`2'` and `3'` I should be able to come up with a better estimate of the center of gravity.

Furthermore, the next frame might yield a forth data point:

[image: Step2]

**This is what I would like to do (but I don't know how):**

based on the individual points (and their relationship to each other) that are returned from the different tracking algorithms, I want to build up a `localization map` of the tracked object. Intuitively I feel like I need to come up with A) an identification function that will identify individual points across frames and B) some cost function that will determine how similar tracked points (and the relationship / distance between them) are from frame to frame, but I can't get my head around on how to implement this. Alternatively, maybe some kind of `map` buildup based on the points will work. But again, I don't know how to approach this.
Any advice (and example code) is highly appreciated!

**EDIT1**
a simple particle filter might probably work too, but I again don't know how to define the cost function. A particle filter for tracking a certain color is easy to program: for each pixel you calculate the difference between target color and pixel color. But how would I do the same for estimating the relationship between tracked points?

**EDIT2** intuitively I feel like Kalman filters could also help with the prediction step. See slides 24 - 32 of this [pdf](http://www.me.uwaterloo.ca/~me597/ME597-Lecture7-LocalizationII.pdf). Or am I misled?

Comment: google "star model" and "hough voting".

Comment: @Shai any particular examples you could refer me to?

Comment: smells very similar to colloid tracking ( https://github.com/tacaswell/trackpy ).  It will link features between frames, can cope with features appearing/disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're trying to do is essentially build up a state space of features, which can be applied to a filtering process, such as an [Extended Kalman Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter). This is a useful framework when you have multiple observations in every frame, and you're trying to estimate or measure something indicated by these observations.

To determine the similarity of the tracked points, you can perform simple template matching from frame to frame for small regions around the points. One way of doing this is to extract an `NxN` (say, `7x7`) region around point `a` in frame `n` and point `a'` in frame `n+1`, followed by [normalised cross correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation) between the extracted regions. This will give you a reasonable measure of how similar the patches are. If the patches are not similar, then you've probably lost track of that point.

Comment: calculating the cross correlation for each point seems like a lot of computation power is needed. wouldn't a probabilistic solution be more advantageous?

Comment: Not really. The two regions are of the same size, and you're not using a sliding window anywhere - just computing a correlation between two surfaces. From experiments I've conducted in the past, this can be achieved in under 1ms for matching a pair of 50x50 regions using simple C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

There is an enormous literature on this and related problems starting in the 80's. Try searching for "optical flow" algorithms".  The input for such algorithms is two successive frames of the same scene.  The output is a vector field, one vector per pixel in the second image, which shows what the direction and speed of movement of the feature in that field.  [This presentation](http://www.vlsi.uwindsor.ca/presentations/2007/4-2Dimensional%20Motion%20Estimation.pdf) is a pretty nice summary.

A nice thing about optical flow is that many algorithms for it parallelize nicely and map onto your favorite video card GPU, so they can run in real time.  Think ESPN overlays.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, in order to identify who is who in each frame, you will have to use a greater dimension. For example if you want to know which point is where between two frame (considering your extracted point are same), you will have to build vectors or simplex and then deduce an organisation between your points (like angles values).

The main problem is that combinations increase with point number. If your camera is a fixed point then, you could use background as a reference in order to deduce object rotations and translations, i mean build vectors between background interest points and object points in order to clearly identify them.
hope that help go forward.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking in to the divided difference filter (DDF), which is similar to the extended Kalman filter (EKF), but does not require an approximate model of the dynamics of your system (which you may not have). Basically the DDF approximates the derivatives used in the EKF using a difference equation. There are plenty of papers online about this, but I do not know whether you have access to them so I have not linked them here. If you are working from a university or a company that has access to online journals (like IEEE Explore), then just [Google "divided difference filter"](https://www.google.com/search?q=divided+difference+filter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and check out some of the papers.

Comment: do you know any links to examples of implementations?

Comment: Sadly I cannot find any that do not require licenses for online journals. If you have a license for IEEE Explore, Science Direct, etc. then you can find plenty of information on these there. You might check whether your local library has some of these journals.